# Continuous non-decreasing image of a measure zero set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am looking at an old qualifying exam to study for my finals; it asks the following true/false question:

Let $f$ be a continuous, non-decreasing function defined on $[0,1]$, and let $E$ be a set of Lebesgue measure zero. Then, $f(E)$ is a set of Lebesgue measure zero.

I suspect this is false, but am not sure. Can anyone think of a solution without using the notion of absolute continuity? The reason for this is because AC won't be covered on the final.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Cantor-Lebesgue function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) $f$ — also known “the devil's staircase” —  is continuous and monotonically increasing. It maps the unit interval onto the unit interval. Since the complement $[0,1] \smallsetminus C$ of the Cantor set $C$ has countable image, $f(C)$ must have measure one.

Comment: @Thomas: I meant what I wrote. $[0,1] = f(C) \cup f(C^c)$ and I argued that $f(C^c)$ is a null-set.

Comment: Ah, okay, thank you. I can't imagine coming up with a function like that on a qual unless one has seen it before!

Comment: @Sid: I think that you could do worse than study that function for your qual -- no one would expect you to come up with it on your own, but they might expect you to know it. It is a standard counterexample to many things. For instance, it is differentiable almost everywhere, and wherever it exists the derivative is zero. Hence $f(x) \neq \int_{0}^x f'(t)\,dt$. Keep it in mind, spend an hour or two of looking at it, it's definitely worth it!

Comment: This function is also the basis for many other counterexamples, for example the one I described today in this answer: a continuous function such that the image of some Lebesgue measurable set is not Lebesgue measurable -  http://math.stackexchange.com/a/92062/630

Comment: @Carl: Thanks for pointing this out. Indeed it is the failure of $f$ to be absolutely continuous that makes the example in your post work -- (which is also the reason that it doesn't satisfy the fundamental theorem of calculus as I mentioned above). It is also one of the standard examples of a function of bounded variation which isn't absolutely continuous.