# Why don't we define a measurable function to be inverse image of measurable set is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In royden's book, he defines a measurable function satisfying that inverse image of $[a, + \infty )$ is measurable. It seems to be quite restrictive, and I understand that my definition in the topic is more general. What are the drawbacks of my definition?

Comment: This is way I've always thought about them.. kind of like with continuous functions with open sets.

Answer (score 10):

You're absolutely right. Here is how it goes..

> **Definition:** If $(X,{\cal A})$ and $(Y,{\cal B})$ are measurable spaces, one says that a function $f\colon X\to Y$ is measurable if $f^{-1}(B)\in{\cal A}$ for every $B\in {\cal B}$.

It's well known that, if ${\cal B}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a set ${\cal S}\subseteq 2^Y$, then $f$ is measurable if and only if $f^{-1}(S)\in{\cal A}$ for every $S\in {\cal S}$.

Therefore, if $Y=\mathbb R$ and ${\cal B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra (which is generated by the set of intervals of the form $[a,\infty[$), then it is sufficient check the condition in the definition only for those intervals.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, the author is considering measurable functions from a measure space $(X,\Sigma)$ to the real line with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. In addition to being generated by open sets in $\mathbb{R}$, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra can be generated by intervals of the form $[a,\infty)$.

Indeed, let $-\infty < a < b < \infty$ and define $$a_n = a + \frac{1}{n} \qquad \text{ and } \qquad b_n = b -\frac{1}{n}$$

Then

$$ (a,b) = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [a_n,b_n)$$

where  $[a_n,b_n)=  [a_n,\infty ) \cap [b_n,\infty)^c$.

Answer (score 3):

Let me rephrase the question a little bit:

Why a function $f: R\to R$ is defined measurable only in the sense of $f: (R, L)\to (R, B),$ where $L$ is Lebesgue measure, and $B$ is Borel measure. In other words, what is the point of non-symmetry here? Why not define a measurable function in the sense of $f: (R, L)\to(R, L)$.

The answer is that to introduce integral, measurable functions in the former sense is sufficient. While measurable in the latter sense is **actually more restrictive**. And there would be  no extra bonus for that restriction.

The last point is only my own opinion. it is nearly impossible that one encounters a function which is measurable in the former sense but not measurable in the latter sense, unless of course someone construct  a counter example deliberately. That function must be very strange, it is not likely you need to deal with one in real life.

Comment: Everything you encounter in real life is assumed to be continuous. So why do we even bother with anything non-continuous?

Comment: And of course, "*unless of course someone construct a counter example deliberately.*". So it is possible to run into a counterexample.

Comment: This is an interesting point (+1). I think the following example may shed some light. Let $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be the Cantor function. Then $g(x)=f(x)+x$ is continuous increasing function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,2]$ so bijective. Because $[0,1]$ is compact and $[0,2]$ is Hausdorff, $g$ is a homemorphism. If $C$ is the (ternary) Cantor set $\subset [0,1]$, then in the complement of $C$ the graph of $g$ has slope $1$ everywhere, so $m(g([0,1]\setminus C))=m([0,1]\setminus C)=1$. Therefore $m(C)=1$. But A) a set of positive Lebesgue measure has non-measurable subsets.

Comment: (cont'd) and B) every subset of a set of Lebesgue measure zero is itself measurable. Consequently there exists a non-measurable subset $A\subset g(C)$, and $g^{-1}(A)$ is measurable as a subset $C$. Therefore $g^{-1}$ is not measurable in the sense of $([0,2],L)\to([0,1],L)$. Even though it is a homeomorphism! My point was that we likely want to include continuous functions in whatever collection we want to study here. So examples like the one above force our hand.

Comment: Anyway, the point I wanted to make was already made by Carl Mummert [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/92062/11619)

Comment: @ interesting reading. the answer by Carl Mummert is informative.